# Can access Drupal home page only

Tags: apache, drupal

I install a Drupal web site on my localhost but I only can access the home page. Other pages I can't access.

> Error:
>
> Object not found!
> The requested URL was not found on this server. The link on the referring page seems to be wrong or outdated. Please inform the author of that page about the error.
>
> If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.
>
> ```
> Error 404
> localhost
> Apache/2.4.23 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.2h PHP/5.5.38
> ```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you access non-rewritten URLs? ex: `/?q=user` ?

Comment: Perhaps post more info about the setup. What pages you tried? Do they exist in Drupal etc

Answer (score 2):

Most likely this is an Apache issue. Please uncomment the following line in Drupal's root `.htaccess`.

`RewriteBase /`

> `# If your site is running in a VirtualDocumentRoot at http://example.com/,`
>
> `# uncomment the following line:`
>
> `# RewriteBase /`

Comment: Then it's a misconfigured Apache. @NeranjaGunarathne – What is http://localhost/admin/reports/status telling you?

Comment: I create a virtual host. then it,s work.thanks every one for support to me.